# In MS Access, is there any way to use a transform query as a subquery in the from clause of a subsequent query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to tidy up an Access database that has way to many queries saved down the left hand side. In particular, I am attempting to consolidate multi-level queries into a single saved query where ever possible and I have run into this problem. I don't understand why the below query won't work and my google-fu has failed me. The error generated is "Syntax error in FROM clause"

N.B. the actual query presented here isn't my exact use case, its the simplest query I could come up with that replicates the issue I'm having.

```
SELECT * 

FROM

( TRANSFORM Sum(Calls_Offered) AS Offered
SELECT CallDate
FROM tblCallData
GROUP BY CallDate
PIVOT Call_Type ) as QryA

ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

If I save the transform query as (e.g.) QryA and then create another query like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM QryA
ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

Then it runs fine, but as far as I was aware there shouldnt be any practical difference between the two? And if thats what I need to do, then fair enough, but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: First, *Date* is a reserved word, so use `[Date]`. Then, I see no *General_Domestic* field ...

Comment: General_Domestic is a call type, the field is created by the transform query. But removing the order by clause completely still generates the same error. and for Date, that could be anything too, it doesn't affect the outcome either, but I will edit the question to reflect your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary (TL;DR)**:  Don't try too hard to find a precise solution, rather try refactoring the queries and don't break something that is working for an "artificial" reason.

---

*First a note of experience*:  This may seem like a subjective, useless answer, but I experienced this type of issue many times as I developed a complex business app.  The final front end has hundreds (thousand?) of queries and SQL statements, as saved queries, SQL in VBA code, and in RecordSource/RowSource properties.

Just like the question describes, a saved query would execute fine where the identical subquery results in an error.  For the record I experienced this with TRANSFORM, UNION, UPDATE, etc... all sorts.  I have even experienced the opposite, where a subquery worked but not an identical saved query.  Vanilla SELECT queries usually don't have these problems, but every now and then even a simple, innocuous change of column list or sort order would cause a perfectly simple, syntactically correct query to "blow up".  I became pretty skilled at **refactoring queries** to get me the same data.  Sometimes changing join types would work, sometimes the order of columns, sometimes saved vs subquery.  Regrettably, I almost never found a reason or consistent solution to any particular problem.

Secondly, I suggest not letting the mess in Access become an obsession.  Don't create an artificial problem out of it by insisting on one technique or organization schema.  Ironically, I usually found it better to split out all the subqueries into saved queries (excepting those which broke... as already mentioned)--the opposite of your intent.  Because the Access query designer does not handle subqueries, this makes management a nightmare in my opinion.  But I still had many subqueries where it seemed to flow best.

I suggest using techniques like naming conventions.  Maximize the Access Navigation pane by defining custom Navigation Categories and Groups.  Beyond that, I even resorted to making simple but effective custom navigation forms where I could group things into tabs, etc.  There are many options, but whatever you chose can be worth the time and effort to organize if your project is making the default list a nightmare.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. There's definitely wisdom here, and you can probably tell I'm pretty new at this. I am more frustrated now this morning that I dont understand WHY it isn't working than anything else, but I think you're right and I need to not waste any more time on it for such little benefit. Thanks again.

Comment: I hope the best... I never want to quash good detective work or finding out what's wrong, but Access (for all its convenience) still has some weird bugs in its database engine.